# How To use Android Accelerometer Detection

Tags: android

i want to know  how to calculate the accelerometer movement.When i place the mobile horizontally in idle state and similarly when i place the mobile in hands,So there accelerometer value change when it is place horizontally or while it is in hand vertically.How To Identify them,Any Sample Codes will be useful

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this example:

[Android: I want to shake it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317428/android-i-want-to-shake-it#comment9376244_2318356)

You can then check time difference between every step and other - this will help you simulate a step.