# How to shake on android 2.2

Tags: android, shake

Does anybody know what is the shake code for android 2.2? I want on shake to make buzz on my application. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
  /* put this into your activity class */
  private SensorManager mSensorManager;
  private float mAccel; // acceleration apart from gravity
  private float mAccelCurrent; // current acceleration including gravity
  private float mAccelLast; // last acceleration including gravity

  private final SensorEventListener mSensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se) {
      float x = se.values[0];
      float y = se.values[1];
      float z = se.values[2];
      mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
      mAccelCurrent = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x*x + y*y + z*z));
      float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
      mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta; // perform low-cut filter
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }
  };

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop() {
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mSensorListener);
    super.onStop();
  }
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317428/android-i-want-to-shake-it)

Comment: Hi Mark.. Its really useful for me.. but i am facing a small problem here.. From this i can find when the shaking get started but i am trying to find when the shaking get stopped.. if could please help me.. where i want to check mAccel value for noshaking...Thanks

Comment: @MarkByers can you explain the math in the onSensorChanged constructor? Thanks a ton, just really interested in whats going on

Answer (score 4):

Here is my code for shake gesture detection:

```
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;


/**
 * Listener that detects shake gesture.
 */
public class ShakeEventListener implements SensorEventListener {


  /** Minimum movement force to consider. */
  private static final int MIN_FORCE = 10;

  /**
   * Minimum times in a shake gesture that the direction of movement needs to
   * change.
   */
  private static final int MIN_DIRECTION_CHANGE = 3;

  /** Maximum pause between movements. */
  private static final int MAX_PAUSE_BETHWEEN_DIRECTION_CHANGE = 200;

  /** Maximum allowed time for shake gesture. */
  private static final int MAX_TOTAL_DURATION_OF_SHAKE = 400;

  /** Time when the gesture started. */
  private long mFirstDirectionChangeTime = 0;

  /** Time when the last movement started. */
  private long mLastDirectionChangeTime;

  /** How many movements are considered so far. */
  private int mDirectionChangeCount = 0;

  /** The last x position. */
  private float lastX = 0;

  /** The last y position. */
  private float lastY = 0;

  /** The last z position. */
  private float lastZ = 0;

  /** OnShakeListener that is called when shake is detected. */
  private OnShakeListener mShakeListener;

  /**
   * Interface for shake gesture.
   */
  public interface OnShakeListener {

    /**
     * Called when shake gesture is detected.
     */
    void onShake();
  }

  public void setOnShakeListener(OnShakeListener listener) {
    mShakeListener = listener;
  }

  @Override
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se) {
    // get sensor data
    float x = se.values[SensorManager.DATA_X];
    float y = se.values[SensorManager.DATA_Y];
    float z = se.values[SensorManager.DATA_Z];

    // calculate movement
    float totalMovement = Math.abs(x + y + z - lastX - lastY - lastZ);

    if (totalMovement > MIN_FORCE) {

      // get time
      long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

      // store first movement time
      if (mFirstDirectionChangeTime == 0) {
        mFirstDirectionChangeTime = now;
        mLastDirectionChangeTime = now;
      }

      // check if the last movement was not long ago
      long lastChangeWasAgo = now - mLastDirectionChangeTime;
      if (lastChangeWasAgo < MAX_PAUSE_BETHWEEN_DIRECTION_CHANGE) {

        // store movement data
        mLastDirectionChangeTime = now;
        mDirectionChangeCount++;

        // store last sensor data 
        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;
        lastZ = z;

        // check how many movements are so far
        if (mDirectionChangeCount >= MIN_DIRECTION_CHANGE) {

          // check total duration
          long totalDuration = now - mFirstDirectionChangeTime;
          if (totalDuration < MAX_TOTAL_DURATION_OF_SHAKE) {
            mShakeListener.onShake();
            resetShakeParameters();
          }
        }

      } else {
        resetShakeParameters();
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Resets the shake parameters to their default values.
   */
  private void resetShakeParameters() {
    mFirstDirectionChangeTime = 0;
    mDirectionChangeCount = 0;
    mLastDirectionChangeTime = 0;
    lastX = 0;
    lastY = 0;
    lastZ = 0;
  }

  @Override
  public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
  }

}
```

Add this in your activity:

```
  private SensorManager mSensorManager;

  private ShakeEventListener mSensorListener;
```

...

in onCreate() add:

```
mSensorListener = new ShakeEventListener();
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener,
        mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);


    mSensorListener.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeEventListener.OnShakeListener() {

      public void onShake() {
        Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Shake!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });
```

and:

```
@Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener,
        mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop() {
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mSensorListener);
    super.onStop();
  }
```

Comment: What is KPBActivityImpl? And where is definition of it.

Comment: It is the name of the activity that is using the detection. I renamed it to 'Activity'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. i am just confusing how to detect when the shaking get stopped.. could you suggest some idea please

Answer (score 2):

It's called "vibrate", as such, as class in question is Vibrator.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *detect* people shaking the phone, you need to implement the [SensorEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html) interface and look for accelerometer events.