# Shaking Android device

Tags: android

How to produce shaking(revaberating) effect in android(Similar to PS2 when a car hit an obstacle)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: I want to shake it!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317428/android-i-want-to-shake-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Vibrator vibrator;
vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
vibrator.vibrate(1000);
```

You will also need android.permission.VIBRATE in the manifest