# Android shaking

Tags: android

I want to add a shake listener to my android application. What i want here, when i will shake my android device it will perform some action. How to do this ? Later i want when my deice will fall down it will produce a sound. How to do this?
Please some body help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will find useful stuff at: [android-shake-detection-listener](http://android.hlidskialf.com/blog/code/android-shake-detection-listener) also look at here: [android-i-want-to-shake-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317428/android-i-want-to-shake-it)

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Chirag: i've not said you to delete your answer. Just warn you that you are giving duplicate answer.