# SensorEventListener no longer detecting in Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, accelerometer, shake

I recently updated my nexus one to Android 2.3.3 and now I am unable to detect a shake with my "SensorEventListener" registered in a SensorManager.  My code is close to this example to detect a shake if you want a concrete example. [Thilo Köhler's shake example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317428/android-i-want-to-shake-it/2318356#2318356).

Does anyone have any ideas on this?  I don't see any differences in the api listed by google going from 2.2 to 2.3 or from 2.3 to 2.3.3 that explicitly talks about this.  I was also unable to find any differences that talk about this.

Comment: To be a tad more specific, it never calls into onAccuracyChanged() with the new api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just re-factoring everything in SensorEventListener's onAccuracyChanged to onSensorChanged.  For those of you looking for a more concrete example of how to do this, here is a good example  [Shaker.java](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Sensor/Shaker/src/com/commonsware/android/shaker/Shaker.java).

Hope this helps anyone else running into this undocumented api functionality change.