# Eager to add shake feature in my android application

Tags: android, animation

i m new to this android application development field  i went through the code that would provide shaking feature but i m unable to understand that for writing this shaking code  I have to create new project or i can add this code in my existing app like gallery (example given in tutorials of android development)  If so  then how??? plzzzz reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swati, if you follow this example: [Sample 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317428/android-i-want-to-shake-it) you can implement that in the same class where you want the shake to be detected

On the other hand, if you follow this example: [Sample 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271448/how-to-detect-shake-event-with-android) you will need to create a new 'class' and then writing that code.

Do let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Thanx!! for the reply ...... can i see this shaking feature on emulator after implementing it?

Comment: Nope, not that I know of Swati, you should be able to try this on any android device. Even low end ones.

Answer (score 2):

Hello swati sinha You hav to use android shake animation. here some hints suppose you want to add shake animation to Edittext.

```
Animation animationShake= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake); 
if(editext.getText().lenght()==0){
edittext.startAnimation(animationShake);
}
```

and shake.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="10" android:duration="1000" 
android:interpolator="@anim/cycle_7" />
```

and cycle_7.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cycleInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      android:cycles="7" />
```

both cycle_7 and shake xml file shud be under res/anim folder.
if You find my answer useful chek as accepted answer