# How to use shake command to stop the narration

Tags: android

I did an application voice narration. But now I need stop the narration when user shakes the application. That means when the user shakes the phone i want to stop the narration. I did the voice narration part.

Comment: Use accelerometers. Look at this question and its answers http://stackoverflow.com/q/5271448/172277

Comment: yah using accelerometers i tried to do.But how i stop the background narration.please give me a code.

Comment: Maybe just tell us how do you do the narration.

Comment: I did it by using this link http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/android-text-to-speech-application.html.I don't know how to put code as a comment.i change previous code little bit.

Comment: I did it by using this link http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/android-text-to-speech-application.html.I don't know how to put code as a comment.i change previous code little bit. thanx for the help

Comment: Edit your question rather than submitting updates as comment.

Comment: Still i can't do it.Please any one knows about the shake functionality

Comment: Do what we told you, improve your question's readability, you might found help.