# On shake action generate on android app

Tags: android, android-sensors

I want to show a message like "you made a shake" when a user shake the android mobile.
That means like when we press a button some action we can create using

```
button.setonclicklistiner()
```

like that i want to do something when a user shake the device.
how can i do that????

Comment: For shaking see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317428/android-i-want-to-shake-it

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271448/how-to-detect-shake-event-with-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Seismic](https://github.com/square/seismic/) from Square.  I haven't used it yet in my own work, but from the example you can declare a shake listener like the following:

```
public class Demo extends Activity implements ShakeDetector.Listener {
  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    ShakeDetector sd = new ShakeDetector(this);
    sd.start(sensorManager);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setGravity(CENTER);
    tv.setText("Shake me, bro!");
    setContentView(tv, new LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT));
  }

  public void hearShake() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Don't shake me, bro!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is actually a really nice looking API

Comment: Yeah, Square puts out some quality open source.

Comment: If you're new to the site the way you say thank you is by upvoting and accepting an answer (clicking check mark).

Comment: what do you mean by API label?

Comment: i am using platform 2.3.3 and api label 10 but it doesnt show anything in the emulator  @johncarl

Comment: Like I mentioned, I have not used this in a project but I don't think this requires much from your project.  Have you tried it on a physical device?