# Pushing accelerometer data into an array

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, accelerometer

I'm having trouble recording the Z-axis data from the accelerometer in an array.

I think I'm probably failing on some basic java rules, but here's what I'm trying to do:

```
    private ArrayList<Float[]> z = new ArrayList<Float[]>();
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                    SensorManager manager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        Sensor accelerometer = manager
                .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
}
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {


                float x = event.values[0];
                float y = event.values[1];
                z.add(event.values[2]);
}
```

But whenever I try to add to the arraylist I get:

> "The method add(Float[]) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (float)"

How can I add the z axis data to an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because your `ArrayList` of `Float[]` type.

Replace the following,

```
 private ArrayList<Float[]> z = new ArrayList<Float[]>();
```

with

```
 ArrayList<Float> z = new ArrayList<Float>();
```

Comment: @Dicky Moore :If this answer helps you then please consider accepting it so that others can get to know about it.

Comment: sure thing! I was just waiting for stackoverflow to allow me to, I had to wait 5 minutes.