# How to detect a tap on the body of the device by using acceleration sensor

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

There are many examples to detect the shake action in Android. However, it is not that easy to detect a single or double tap on the device based on accelerometer data. A normal move or gentle shake may be detected as tap easily. Anybody know how to find out the tap among so many acceleration events?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? What have you looked at?

Comment: Yes, I tried the shake action according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271448/how-to-detect-shake-event-with-android. I also tried the high-pass filter to get the event value I need. I'll try more possible solutions and will update here.

Comment: Awesome! I'm really glad that you looked at some other information. Once you have that figured out, feel free to edit your question and add that information.

Answer (score -1):

My experience with the accelerometer is a little limited, but I suppose you could have a thread or a service that constantly monitors accelerometer data.

Within that thread I feel like you could create a vector by adding all of the components (x,y,z) and find the magnitude of the resulting vector. From that, you know if it I'd a tap if you have 2 large resultant vectors in rapid succession (one for when you start the tap, one for when you stop the tap) . Then you could have that release an intent or notify your program in some way.

Feel free to ask any questions you might have about this in comments.