# How to detect shake in LIbgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am using libgdx framework for my android game and I need to detect if the user has shaken the mobile device, so how can I do that?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271448/how-to-detect-shake-event-with-android

Comment: You can get the accelerometer via Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX() or Y or Z

Comment: @Yasen Bagalev but I am using libgdx

Comment: Ok, just check the first answer. You can copy the  method, call it in the render method and replace lets say x = values[SensorManager.DATA_X]; with Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX();
The method of shake detection is the same on every platform/library. Just try to figure out how it works and use the accelerometer data