# detect Shake in android

Tags: android, android-sensors, shake

I am trying to hit an API when user shake a device 10 times. I have tried many git sample and stack overflow solution but non of them did solve my problem. Some of them detecting shake before 10 times or after 10 times. I have tried [Seiamic](https://github.com/square/seismic) and [ShakeDetector](https://github.com/tbouron/ShakeDetector) libraries. Please give me some valuable solution.

Comment: It's not that simple with multiple consecutive shakes. I believe you'll need to define what a **shake** is and what's the **timeout** between two shakes by yourself in order to be satisfied with the solution

Answer (score 3):

**I have done that using this library :**

1. Add the dependecy in your build.gridle file

   ```
   allprojects {
     repositories {
       ...
       maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
     }
   }

   dependencies {
     compile 'com.github.safetysystemtechnology:android-shake-detector:v1.2'
   }
   ```
2. Give the permission to your app manifest file

   ```
   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />
   ```

   if you will run in background, register your broadcast receiver

   ```
   <receiver android:name=".ShakeReceiver">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="shake.detector" />
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```
3. start that in onCreate method Like this :

   ```
    private ShakeDetector shakeDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buildView();

        ShakeOptions options = new ShakeOptions()
                .background(true)
                .interval(1000)
                .shakeCount(2)
                .sensibility(2.0f);

        this.shakeDetector = new ShakeDetector(options).start(this, new ShakeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onShake() {
                Log.d("event", "onShake");
            }
        });

        //IF YOU WANT JUST IN BACKGROUND
        //this.shakeDetector = new ShakeDetector(options).start(this);
    }
   ```
4. override onStop method and stop that

   ```
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        shakeDetector.stopShakeDetector(getBaseContext());
    }
   ```
5. override onDestroy method and destroy like this :

   ```
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        shakeDetector.destroy(getBaseContext());
        super.onDestroy();
    }
   ```

(*) Optional step : if you will run in background, create your broadcast receiver

```
public class ShakeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (null != intent && intent.getAction().equals("shake.detector")) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By Using **SensorListener**

Please check this ticked answer...

You have to adjust **SHAKE_THRESHOLD** value to achieve this

[How to detect shake event with android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271448/how-to-detect-shake-event-with-android)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

have a static variable that gets incremented every time a shake is detected.

```
static int count = 0;
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
    long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if ((curTime - mLastShakeTime) > MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_SHAKES_MILLISECS) {

        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];

        double acceleration = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) +
                Math.pow(y, 2) +
                Math.pow(z, 2)) - SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;

        if (acceleration > SHAKE_THRESHOLD) {
            mLastShakeTime = curTime;
            count++;
            if(count==10){
                //your code goes here
            }
        }
    }
}
```