# Listen to an event at all times, even when app is not being used or running

Tags: java, android

So, I saw this [Shake flashlight](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidrocker.shakeflashlight&hl=en_IN) app on Android that turns on the flashlight everytime I shake the phone. I want to implement something like this, which is listening to an event ***(Shake event or a Volume button down press etc)*** at all times on the device and runs a piece of code when that happens. I referred [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38633936/detect-shake-in-android#answer-54745560) and used the library `safetysystemtechnology:android-shake-detector:v1.2`. 
Currently I have a broadcast listener that listens to the shake event and this works fine as long as the app is running or is in the background. However if I close the app, I see the `Application terminated` log and then it stops detecting. My understanding was that an event is broadcasted to every app that is registered to (even when it is not active) like how apps like TrueCaller shows the name when a call is received, even when that app is not being used. ***Is the Broadcast receiver a right way to implement this functionality?*** I've heard about `WorkManager` which also looked like something that could be helpful.

**Step 1:** I added the dependencies to gradle files and added the permissions

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    ...
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
  }
}

dependencies {
   compile 'com.github.safetysystemtechnology:android-shake-detector:v1.2'
}
```

Android Manifest

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />
```

**Step 2:** Registered the received in Manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".ShakeReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="shake.detector" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**Step 3:** Created the receiver class and implemented onRecieve method

```
public class ShakeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (null != intent && intent.getAction().equals("shake.detector")) {
            System.out.println("Shake happened");
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 4:** In the Main Activity, created the shake detector object and started  running it

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ShakeDetector shakeDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ShakeOptions options = new ShakeOptions()
                .background(true)
                .interval(1000)
                .shakeCount(2)
                .sensibility(2.0f);


        this.shakeDetector = new ShakeDetector(options).start(this);
    }
```

Comment: *A service is a background work running at all times.* no it's not. Services don't run "at all times" and also they run on the main thread so no background work either

Comment: For the OP, check out this link: https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/foreground-service

Comment: I expect you'll need to use a foreground service for this to work on the most recent version of Android - that would allow you to register for receiving accelerometer broadcasts. However, I'm fairly sure that listening to volume key presses will require an Activity. Foreground services will require a notification to always be present in the notification tray though.