# How to detect user is shaking the phone in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an application where something has to happen when the user shakes the phone. I think there is no native way of doing this, but I'm not sure. Is there an easy way to do this? Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271448/how-to-detect-shake-event-with-android