# Fetching direction from Accelerometer using shake action

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

I have made android app that plays next song when shake once using Accelerometer.

Now what i want my in app if a shake the phone in right side it should play the next song in line or if shake in left play previous, **can i do it with the logic of axis found at time of shake action** if that is possible 
**how can I put axis to the methods of motion detection to know the direction in which the mobile is shaked**. If any one have a logic for this please help i am stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some digging into this and was able to resolve it myself. but while posting the answer I [found this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6225656/4079010) by **Basil** which explains better than my implementation. So, i found it more helpful.

> what he did

In the **onSensorChanged** whenever the device receives new value it store the values into variables after some delay. After that **compares the new value with previous values** beautifully. Which leads to calculate into direction the device has shakes. If the answer is still unclear let me know.

```
public class ShakeActivity extends Activity implements SensorListener {
// For shake motion detection.
private SensorManager sensorMgr;
private long lastUpdate = -1;
private float x, y, z;
private float last_x, last_y, last_z;
private static final int SHAKE_THRESHOLD = 800;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.main);
// start motion detection
sensorMgr = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
boolean accelSupported = sensorMgr.registerListener(this,
    SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER,
    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

    if (!accelSupported) {
        // on accelerometer on this device
        sensorMgr.unregisterListener(this,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER);
    }
}

protected void onPause() {
    if (sensorMgr != null) {
        sensorMgr.unregisterListener(this,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER);
        sensorMgr = null;
    }
    super.onPause();
}

public void onAccuracyChanged(int arg0, int arg1) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values) {
    if (sensor == SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER) {
        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // only allow one update every 100ms.
        if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > 100) {
        long diffTime = (curTime - lastUpdate);
        lastUpdate = curTime;

        x = values[SensorManager.DATA_X];
        y = values[SensorManager.DATA_Y];
        z = values[SensorManager.DATA_Z];

        if(Round(x,4)>10.0000){
            Log.d("sensor", "X Right axis: " + x);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Right shake detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(Round(x,4)<-10.0000){
            Log.d("sensor", "X Left axis: " + x);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Left shake detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        float speed = Math.abs(x+y+z - last_x - last_y - last_z) / diffTime * 10000;

        // Log.d("sensor", "diff: " + diffTime + " - speed: " + speed);
        if (speed > SHAKE_THRESHOLD) {
            //Log.d("sensor", "shake detected w/ speed: " + speed);
            //Toast.makeText(this, "shake detected w/ speed: " + speed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        last_x = x;
        last_y = y;
        last_z = z;
        }
    }
}

public static float Round(float Rval, int Rpl) {
float p = (float)Math.pow(10,Rpl);
Rval = Rval * p;
float tmp = Math.round(Rval);
return (float)tmp/p;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir this logic is what I wanted so badly  also like to thank the source of this answer *Mr Basil* thank you.

Comment: Your welcome @krishank tripathi. Would you like to award bounty to me?