# Android how to work with sensor?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I want when I shake my phone it randomly generate some no.
I am working with API2.2 and try to using `SensorListener` but it shows that it is deprecated.
so which one I have to use.

please give me any suggestion how to do this.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Xion said, use `SensorEventListener`.  There are many examples of this here on SO; for instance, check out [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317428/android-i-want-to-shake-it).  For testing shakes in an emulator, something like [SensorSimulator](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator) might also help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SensorEventListener` instead. There is quite good explanation of it in the docs. Accelorometer is probably the sensor you want to use here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an exemple of how to use the sensor manager class on android:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html