# How to work with android's existing BlueToothChat Application

Tags: android, bluetooth

Android already have BluetoothChat application. Using that app two devices chat with each other.
I am trying little different. Instead of chat I want whatever I write in my `EditText` and shake the mobile means it will appear in 2nd device.

Means BluetoothChat have one `EditText` and a "send" button. Whatever we write within EditText and press "send" means it send. But instead of button I want to use Sensor.

I also did the sensor for shaking separately. But problem is how can I merge both so that the bluetooth work for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the code in this answer:
[Android: I want to shake it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317428/android-i-want-to-shake-it/2318356#2318356)

Add the code from the above answer to the BluetoothChat activity.
The following code is executed anytime the user hits the "Send" button in BluetoothChat:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            // Send a message using content of the edit text widget
            TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
            String message = view.getText().toString();
            sendMessage(message);
        }
```

Add that code (except the method declaration) to the code in the above answer, inside `onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se)`, but ONLY if mAccel > 2.

Comment: Where I should modify that I am not getting. Plz tell me

Comment: @Jyosna I modified my answer to be more specific.