# SpeechToText on Shake of phone not working properly

Tags: android

In my application,i want to use TextToSpeech when users shakes the phone. I have handled shaking of phone successfully using-

[Android: I want to shake it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317428/android-i-want-to-shake-it)

But problem came when i intigrated TextToSpeech with this code.

Tried this- http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/TextToSpeechActivity.html

It gave me no error but can't hear speech when tried in real device.

Also tried using this code:

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/android-text-to-speech-application.html

But it gives me force close in real device so i can't get idea about error. I can't test shaking on immulator so can't find out even there.

Any help is appriciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it... I didn't install TTS engine.It is working fine now.Silly me!