# How can I add shake functionality in my Android application?

Tags: android, animation

I want to develop an application with some advance features like shake feature, orientation of images, zoom in/out, scrolling, etc. For instance, the
user can shake the phone in order to erase an entered text. Also, by rotating the phone
clockwise or anti-clockwise, the orientation of the underlying images will change.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For shaking:

You will need to use the phone's accelerometer sensor.  You can find many examples of this if you Google (for example: [Android: I want to shake it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317428/android-i-want-to-shake-it))

For rotations:

When the phone detects an orientation change, Android will destroy and recreate your application.  There are lifecycle methods (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) that are called that allow you to save and restore your application's current state.  Again, if you Google:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html
http://www.androidguys.com/2008/10/14/rotational-forceson-your-android-app/

Comment: Thanks  ! I have tried like  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317428/android-i-want-to-shake-it  . But it gives only Toast message  for shake, but if i tried to write some code for image changing when i shaked the phone it  is not possible, how can i write the code for change the image .

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks amb !  I have added the VIBRATE permission to make it work: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />