# android accelerometer registerListener

Tags: android, accelerometer, sampling

I am new to android and working on accelerometer. I want to collect 20 samples of x,y,z per second, for this can I use the following? registerListener(SensorEventListener listener, Sensor sensor, int rate)in the int rate can I use 3000000(microseconds) so that I get one x,y,z value for every 3000000(microseconds) or 3 seconds so it would be like registerListener(this, Accelerometer , 3000000); and get 20 samples of x,y,z in 1 seconds. If I am wrong can anyone suggest me how to solve this?

Comment: Deprecated Use `SensorEventListener` instead.
[Android: I want to shake it][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317428/android-i-want-to-shake-it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the Javadocs for [SensorManager.registerListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener%28android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int%29)

You need to pass in one of the 4 constants, you cannot enter an arbitrary value like you are trying to do.

> The rate sensor events are delivered at. This is only a hint to the system. Events may be received faster or slower than the specified rate. Usually events are received faster. The value must be one of SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SENSOR_DELAY_UI, SENSOR_DELAY_GAME, or SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST or, the desired delay between events in microsecond.

so an example call might look like this:

```
registerListener(this, Accelerometer , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```

**EDIT:** *Tim.footInMouth()* I didn't see the last part of the definition. You can actually pass it microseconds.

I think the math for your seconds is off a little

You want 20 samples per second (1000 milliiseconds)

So you want 1 sample per 50 milliseconds

A [microsecond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) is 1/1000 of a millisecond

So 1000 microseconds = 1 milisecond

and 50,000 microseconds = 50 millisecond = 20 times per second.

So your call should be:

```
registerListener(this, Accelerometer , 50000);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!can you suggest me an alternative solution?

Comment: Did you see the part after the edit? I think that is the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you.You are so quick!So this means that after 50000 microseconds public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) would be called?Or I am wrong? All I want is to store each x,y,z sample values with each sample having a 50000 microsec difference

Comment: I don't know exactly, I don't have any experience with the Accelerometer. Did you try running it?

Comment: yes I have tried but need clarity on when the onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) method is called, is it called each and every second or only after 50000sec, and from where is it called