# How to finish an activity on device shaken in android

Tags: android, android-activity, accelerometer, shake, activity-finish

I just want to finish current activity when i shake my device for 2 seconds. What should i do for that? Can anyone guide me please.

Comment: I think by accelerometer api you would get threshold not time......

Answer (score 2):

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener
{
   onCreate()...

   public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
   {
     if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
     {
        // your code here
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [SensorEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html). Here are some [sample codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317428/android-i-want-to-shake-it) to get you started with.

Answer (score 0):

On a `while` loop, receive your Sensor data and decide whether you're in the middle of a shaking sequence. If so, you can keep a timestamp variable and pull the event timestamp in order to do this until 2 seconds have passed.

@gtumca-MAC showed you how to use the sensor events, just check the Google API documentation for further details, it's really well explained.