# Can anyone tell me how i get toast when mobile falls down?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am making an android project to detect when mobile fall down, can anyone tell me which sensor should I use in my app, I know accelerometer will use for this kind of purpose, but accelerometer can also detect when I shake the phone in my hand and I want to get the toast only when the mobile falls down. 
here is my code:

```
int count = 1;
    private boolean init;
    private Sensor mySensor;
    private SensorManager SM;
    private float x1, x2, x3;
    private static final float ERROR = (float) 7.0;
    private static final float SHAKE_THRESHOLD = 15.00f; // m/S**2
    private static final int MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_SHAKES_MILLISECS = 1000;
    private long mLastShakeTime;
       public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

                long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if ((curTime - mLastShakeTime) > MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_SHAKES_MILLISECS) {

                    float x = event.values[0];
                    float y = event.values[1];
                    float z = event.values[2];

                    double acceleration = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2)
                            + Math.pow(z, 2))
                            - SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
                    Log.d("mySensor", "Acceleration is " + acceleration + "m/s^2");

                    if (acceleration > SHAKE_THRESHOLD) {
                        mLastShakeTime = curTime;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FALL DETECTED",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } } }}
```

Comment: What actually happens? You detect a fall but you also detect shakes? Which values do you get in Log.d if you shake it and which when you drop it (I assume on not-so-but-enough-hard surface)?

Comment: @CloudWalker its show positive value when i shake and negative on fall. on shake :
04-14 09:46:53.206 24230-24230/? D/mySensor: Acceleration is 12.087330033651629m/s^2                                                                         On fall :  04-14 09:46:53.606 24230-24230/? E/in second: 0.0
        04-14 09:46:53.606 24230-24230/? D/mySensor: Acceleration is -7.812465535485355m/s^2

Comment: Maybe you should not use MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_SHAKES_MILLISECS. Imagine, phone is in your hand (or pocket, or on the table). Some action nudges it (small spike) then phone is weightless for less than a second and then it hits the ground (several shakes where one is big spike) then nothing for a second or two (until owner picks it up). You should not filter at all by time: you should go through all those events recording biggest spikes and their time and then verify if conforms with sequence: shake (smaller spikes), weightlessness for a short time,  big spike, default gravity for couple of seconds.

Comment: ok but my question is simple i want a toast only when i drop the phone, i   don't think  removing time event will do this.

Comment: i mean i am getting toast in both cases shake and fall how can i distinguish the shake event and fall event i also change threshold value positive to negative but i still don't get right output .

Comment: What about my answer you don't understand? Your question is simple but solution is obviously not so simple as you would want it. I mean, there is no simple fix to your code to make it work. You have to put more effort into it and I explained general notions you must take into account.

Comment: yes i know sir but can please suggest me a fine solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109121/discussion-between-cloudwalker-and-abhishek).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all i done this by myself a little change was get me rid of this , that is just taking two variable set those values negative and call them as threshold value of acceleration .
thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Fall Sensor", your guess in using the accelerometer is right. Record and measure the accelerometer data when it falls and deduct a model from there.

Comment: i did that but it give me toast when i shake it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use accelerometer. But it will detect very small movement.

The only way to do is , get the difference between two readings on change of state.

If its very very high, the mobile has traveled a longer distances say fell down from hand, or change an abnormal position say a shock.

Comment: i know that , but how can get the toast only when mobile fall , its not so simple get the difference because we can't use two threshold values.

Comment: why is it difficult.. have two variables previousValue and current value.. compare the previous value and currentValue at onSensorChanged/onAccuracyChanged methods.//. if the difference is Ok.. then show toast.. else assign the currentValue to previousvalue..

Answer (score 0):

For this we have to use little bit of Physics, **any object falling under the influence of gravity has an acceleration of 9.8 m/s/s**, downward (on Earth). SO with this knowledge we can get the downward direction speed
**1)based on the axis(Y-axis) using accelerometer check it is downward and

2) check if it is equal to this 9.8 m/s constant and also check the**

if the fall speed is approx near 9.8 m/s show the toast

Comment: i did it's wrong and dont know why you are doing sqrt on the value you should use only Y axis data read this http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-accelerometer-on-android--mobile-22125 also look at the diagram its should give you an idea

Comment: i am taking that because mobile can't fall on y axis only, suppose if i throw it then it move on x-axis

Comment: in that case you can't use that gravitational constant

Comment: sounds interesting will work on it this weekend if you are not able to proceed

Comment: BUT keep trying, as i MIGHT get time to do this this weekend

Comment: Great please accept the answer if the suggestion was helpful, also post the updated answer so that it can be useful to others

Comment: no i didn't use your suggestion, i made that by myself